# C# ChromiumWebBrowser Get Image (Captcha)

Tags: javascript, c#, chromium, cefsharp

I am developing a browser application with C#.
I use **CefSharp (ChromiumBrowser)** as a browser.
This application automatically logs in to a particular website.

There is a captcha on the site. I need to pull this captcha into the pictureBox.
I have no idea about this.

I tried the `execCommand('copy')` function with JavaScript, but failed because `createControlRange()`, which is in normal webBrowser, is not in Chrome.

**The link is fixed, a new captcha comes up every time it is refreshed.** So I will have to shoot the captcha in the current image.

I was doing this successfully with the standard (IE) web browser. (C# DOM)

```
dynamic body = webBrowser1.Document.Body.DomElement;
dynamic controlRange = body.createControlRange();
dynamic element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("guvenlik_kod").DomElement;
controlRange.add(element);
controlRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null); //copy with command.
pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap); //transfers the image on the clipboard.
```

**Calling JavaScript code in Chromium Web Browser just happens this way. I have no idea how to get a return.**

`Task<JavascriptResponse> response =  browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(js_code);`

The installation link: [Telerik ChromiumWebBrowser Help Center](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/details/how-to-embed-chrome-browser-in-a-winforms-application)

[Captcha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN8rL.png)

**There is some information here as a document.**
[CefSharp Wiki](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript)

I'm waiting for your help.

**I'm sorry that my English is bad.**

Comment: Do you have permission from the website owners to interact with their website in this way? It's exactly this kind of behavior that has lead google to start blocking CEF based browsers https://security.googleblog.com/2019/04/better-protection-against-man-in-middle.html

Comment: @amaitland You got me wrong. The application I made is not a malicious application. I'm making an app to make site query site and things easier.
Permissions were received. You can only think of it as a desktop application.
As in Github. Since the site has no web service, we were asked to do it this way.

Comment: Displaying the captcha in the browser sounds like a better option. Concept as a whole sounds questionable.